# Facebook shares of a post not displaying results

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do I get the shares from Facebook Graph ?

I am getting a blank result for

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/<postid>/sharedposts?access_token=<access_token>
```

while things like

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/<postid>/comments?access_token=<access_token>
```

and

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/<postid>/likes?access_token=<access_token>
```

are giving correct results.

By blank results, I mean :

```
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the Access Token you're using is missing the `read_stream` permission, as described in

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/object/sharedposts

> A user access token with read_stream permission, for someone who is able to view the post after privacy settings are taken into account.